# Как работать с git через HTTP прокси на Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, git

При попытке извлечения кода git выдает ошибку:

```
repo init -u git://...

Getting repo ...
   from git://...
fatal: Unable to look up ... (port 9418) (Name or service not known)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно прописать параметры прокси в настройках git.

1. Создать скрипт git_proxy_command.sh

   ```
   (echo "CONNECT $1:$2 HTTP/1.0"; echo; cat ) | nc прокси порт | (read a; read a; cat )
   ```
2. Установить переменную окружения GIT_PROXY_COMMAND

   ```
   export GIT_PROXY_COMMAND=git_proxy_command.sh
   ```